# Parsing UTC Time in JSON.net

Tags: json.net

I have a JSON file which I have deserialized into a class I created called MyType

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);
```

One of the JSON properties is Time which is expressed in UTC. 
I take this UTC Time and convert it into a DATETIME object

```
DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(
    JsonTime, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

The above works fine when the UTC Time is: 2014-06-25T00:30:07.9289078+00:00

But pukes on : 2014-06-24T00:31:08.62124+00:00

I suspect it's most likely because of the missing trailing "0"s before the "+"

I was playing around with JSON.net and was trying to use the Jtoken.Parse method which seems to be doing what I want.

```
var t = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(
      @"{ ""x"": ""2014-06-24T00:31:08.62124+00:00"" }").Value<DateTime>("x");
```

How is JToken.Parse converting this UTC Time correctly and how can I use it in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);` ?

I tried to set this

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings1
{
  get
  {
     return new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime};
  }
}
.......
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json, JsonSerializerSettings1);
```

It still does not convert the UTC into date time during deserialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try setting `DateFormatHandling` to `IsoDateFormat` and `DateTimeZoneHandling` to `Utc`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""Date"": ""2014-06-24T00:31:08.62124+00:00"" }";

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
        };

        MyType obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json, settings);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.Date.ToString());
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```